# iOS - How send message to facebook friends

Tags: ios, facebook, message

I am trying to integrate into my app (iOS 5+) a way to send a private text message to a friend on facebook.

After research I found this chat:
https://github.com/KanybekMomukeyev/FacebookChat

Can anyone explain to me how to send just the message without the all chat features?

Is it necessary to use the XMPP framework?

**--- Resolved ---**

I ended up resolving the issue otherwise, using the send dialog available at

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/

Comment: "It is not supported on mobile devices."  Did you use a webview?